# Pickle Security Risk for Personal Use

Tags: python, security, save, pickle

I am currently working on a small rpg to learn object oriented programming. I have got a nice little game and I was looking into implementing a "save" option to it.

I had a look online and came across this [handy tutorial](http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2012/05/03/implement-a-save-game-feature-in-python-with-the-shelve-module/) proposing to use the `shelve` module which uses `pickle` to store the variables and instances to save.

I have done a bit of reading around pickle security issues and a lot of it seems to be related to risks when un-pickling data from  unknown sources or which could have been modified.

My question is: if I intend to use my game at home on my personal computer, is there a real risk ? Am I any more at risk of malicious programs than I would be normally (i.e someone hacking into my computer in the first place and adding malicious code to the pickled data). I have a good anti-virus (NOD32) ... would that be of any help ?

Any alternatives would be welcome but my programming and computer science knowledge is limited and I feel like playing around with JSON or the like might be a greater risk to my computer if I have no idea what I'm doing and playing it by trial and error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no real risk if you are using this to *locally* store data.

That's because if a hacker can alter the files on your disk, you have far bigger problems; the hacker has already compromised your system. The user of your program can't be seen as a risk here, they already can run their own Python programs that can do everything the pickle module can do.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, but I just wanted to check.